# use joomla weather output in other site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla site and installed a weather module, and now weather is shown in page.

I have another site without Joomla cms (PHP)

How can I use a Joomla weather module output in my PHP site?

Extension I use : http://www.joomshaper.com/joomla-extensions/sp-weather

module some code:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');    
$moduleName             = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$moduleID               = $module->id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to integrate directly with the yahoo weather api.

http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Comment: but that is ridiculous, it is a joomla module which uses the api I liked to. Its like saying I want to use a joomla module on my drupal site, they are not compatible and re-engineering a joomla module to work with your PHP site is going to be a significant amount of work.